# Register .ocx and .dll files with Heat.exe (alternative to regsvr32)

Tags: wix, wix3.7, regsvr32

I am quite new to WiX and am having trouble figuring out how to register .ocx and .dll files. At first I thought I'd use a custom action with the 'ExeCommand' attribute. However, I could not get this to work and the research I did online suggested that there are better ways to do it involving heat.exe and registry keys.

I have very little experience with the windows registry or heat.exe. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Are the .ocx and .dll files yours? If not, it is better to use the 3rd party's installer. You can chain installers using a WiX Bootstrapper project.

Comment: I'm creating this installer from scratch. Some of the files are mine and some of them might already be on the system. I want to register my files, search the system to see if it contains the others and register the ones that are missing.

Comment: For 3rd party files, look for redistributable installers in the form of .exe, .msi, or .msm files. .exe and .msi files can be chained in a bootstrapper. .msm files can be included in your setup with WiX `Merge` and `MergeRef` elements.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me now. Those "3rd party" dll and ocx files are normally found in the Windows\System32 folder. I want to make sure they are there and possibly register a few of them if they are missing. And I want to register my own files as well. I'm not quite sure what you mean when you talk about a 3rd party installer.